# Trying to load an application's icon(s) using LoadImage, but the function returns 0

Tags: vb.net, winapi, icons, native-methods

I am trying to load an application's icon(s) using the `LoadImage` WinAPI function, but for some reason it always returns 0.

I have read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx), but I cannot understand what I've done wrong. I get no exceptions except for when trying to convert `IconPtr` to `Icon` (which is becasue `IconPtr` is 0).

```
Public Shared Function ExtractAssociatedIconArray(ByVal File As String, ByVal Sizes() As Size) As Icon()
    Dim ReturnArray(Sizes.Length) As Icon
    Dim Index As Integer = 0

    For Each s As Size In Sizes
        'IconPtr is always zero for some reason.
        Dim IconPtr As IntPtr = NativeMethods.LoadImage(Nothing, File, NativeMethods.Enumrations.IMAGE_ICON, s.Width, s.Height, NativeMethods.Enumrations.LR_DEFAULTCOLOR Or NativeMethods.Enumrations.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
        ReturnArray(Index) = Icon.FromHandle(IconPtr)
        Index += 1
    Next

    Return ReturnArray
End Function
```

The `NativeMethods` class:

```
Public Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function LoadImage(ByVal hInst As IntPtr, _
                     ByVal lpszName As String,
                     ByVal uType As UInt32, _
                     ByVal cxDesired As Integer, _
                     ByVal cyDesired As Integer, _
                     ByVal fuLoad As UInt32) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Enum Enumrations As UInteger
        '' LoadImage ''
        IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
        IMAGE_ICON = 1
        IMAGE_CURSOR = 2
        LR_CREATEDIBSECTION = &H2000
        LR_DEFAULTCOLOR = &H0
        LR_DEFAULTSIZE = &H40
        LR_LOADFROMFILE = &H10
        LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS = &H1000
        LR_LOADTRANSPARENT = &H20
        LR_MONOCHROME = &H1
        LR_SHARED = &H8000
        LR_VGACOLOR = &H80
    End Enum
End Class
```

Usage example:

```
Dim Icons() As Icon = ExtractAssociatedIconArray("C:\MyApp.exe", New Size() {New Size() {48, 48}})
```

Comment: From the documentation (even from the name of the method), it seems that the returned handle is associated with an image rather than with an icon. Have you tried to convert the output into an image/bitmap (and this variable into an icon)?

Comment: An EXE file normally contains multiple icons.  Note how you never specified which one you want.  Nor is that particularly easy to find out, icon resource IDs are arbitrary.  So you are just using the wrong winapi function to get the job done.  Use Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() instead.

Comment: @varocarbas : That doesn't matter since the function returns 0 either way.

Comment: @HansPassant : I read in a SO answer that LoadImage will get the icon/image closest to the size you specified. Unfortuately I don't have the link to that answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

I managed to solve my own problem by using the `ExtractIconEx` function instead.

```
Public Shared Function ExtractAssociatedIcons(ByVal File As String) As AssemblyIconCollection
    Dim IconCount As Integer = NativeMethods.ExtractIconEx(File, -1, Nothing, Nothing, 0)
    Dim AssemblyIcons As New AssemblyIconCollection

    'The 'Icon handle' arrays.
    Dim LargeIcons(IconCount) As IntPtr
    Dim SmallIcons(IconCount) As IntPtr

    'Extract icons into the two arrays of handles.
    NativeMethods.ExtractIconEx(File, 0, LargeIcons, SmallIcons, IconCount)

    'Add each large icon to the "LargeIcons" list.
    For Each ptr As IntPtr In LargeIcons
        If ptr = IntPtr.Zero Then Continue For

        Dim Ico As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(ptr)
        If Ico.Width < 25 Or Ico.Height < 25 Then Continue For
        AssemblyIcons.LargeIcons.Add(Ico)
    Next

    'Add each small icon to the "SmallIcons" list.
    For Each ptr As IntPtr In SmallIcons
        If ptr = IntPtr.Zero Then Continue For

        Dim Ico As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(ptr)
        If Ico.Width > 24 Or Ico.Height > 24 Then Continue For
        AssemblyIcons.SmallIcons.Add(Ico)
    Next

    'Return the output class.
    Return AssemblyIcons
End Function
```

My `AssemblyIconCollection` class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class AssemblyIconCollection
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the large icons found in the assembly.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property LargeIcons As List(Of Icon)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the small icons found in the assembly.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property SmallIcons As List(Of Icon)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.LargeIcons = New List(Of Icon)
        Me.SmallIcons = New List(Of Icon)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the `ExtractIconEx` declaration:

```
Public Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Shared Function ExtractIconEx(ByVal szFileName As String, _
         ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, _
         ByVal phiconLarge() As IntPtr, _
         ByVal phiconSmall() As IntPtr, _
         ByVal nIcons As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function
End Class
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim Icons As AssemblyIconCollection = ExtractAssociatedIcons("C:\myfile.exe")

'Iterating every large icon.
For Each LargeIcon As Icon In Icons.LargeIcons
    'Do stuff.
Next

'Iterating every small icon.
For Each SmallIcon As Icon In Icons.SmallIcons
    'Do stuff.
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the wrong way. You are passing an executable file name to the `lpszName` argument of `LoadImage`. That parameter does not accept an executable file name. It accepts the name of the resource within the module specified by the first parameter, `hinst`. This is explained in the documentation.

You note that you are not encountering exceptions. That's to be expected. The Win32 API won't raise exceptions. Again the documentation describes how errors are reported. They are reported by the return value being `NULL`. And when that occurs, you call `GetLastError` to obtain an error code. That would be `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` from .net.

To do what you are attempting using `LoadImage` you need to do the following:

1. Obtain an instance handle by calling `LoadLibraryEx` passing the executable file name. Use the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag, as described by the documentation.
2. Pass that instance handle to `LoadImage`. You will also need to know the name of the image resource that you wish to extract.
3. If you don't know the name of the resource, you'll need to use the resource enumeration functions, e.g. `EnumResourceNames`. You are looking for the first resource in the executable.

Comment: Oh... So I misunderstood the documentation :). I'll have a look at what you suggest. It just has to be hard to extract icons of a wanted size from an .exe, has it? (:

Comment: @VisualVincent: It's not hard, just tedious. [Icons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) has all the information you need (*The Icon API: Raw Resource Bytes*). To find the icon ID of the desired size, call [LookupIconIdFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074.aspx), and manually construct the icon. Or use [CreateIconFromResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I managed to solve it using `ExtractIconEx`. You've taught me some valuable things though. :)