# How to get count of stored icons into a file?

Tags: vb.net

Into a project that I am working on, there is a **function** by the name "**ReturnIcon**" which extracts icons from `.exe`, `.dll`, `.ico` etc and return them to bitmap.

```vb
Declare Function ExtractIcon Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconExA" (ByVal lpszFile As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, ByRef phiconLarge As Integer, ByRef phiconSmall As Integer, ByVal nIcons As Integer) As Integer

Public Function ReturnIcon(ByVal Path As String, ByVal Index As Integer, Optional ByVal small As Boolean = False) As Icon
    Dim bigIcon As Integer
    Dim smallIcon As Integer

    ExtractIcon(Path, Index, bigIcon, smallIcon, 1)
    If bigIcon = 0 Then
        ExtractIcon(Path, 0, bigIcon, smallIcon, 1)
    End If

    If bigIcon <> 0 Then
        If small = False Then
            Return Icon.FromHandle(bigIcon)
        Else
            Return Icon.FromHandle(smallIcon)
        End If
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

And you can use it like this:

```
X_Control.Image = ReturnIcon(IconPath, 0, 0).ToBitmap
```

I would like to add the ability so I can get count of stored icons for selected file. There is anyway to add it into this function? Should I make a new one for this? Any example would be really appreciatable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was under my nose. I just had to do this...

```
Public Declare Function ExtractIcon Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconExA" (ByVal lpszFile As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, ByRef phiconLarge As Integer, ByRef phiconSmall As Integer, ByVal nIcons As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim count As Integer = ExtractIcon(FilePath, -1, Nothing, Nothing, 0)
    NumericUpDown.Maximum = count
End Sub
```

Comment: can u add a lil bit of explanation of the code plz?

Comment: @zackraiyan You just need to read the documentation for ExtractIcon.

Comment: @zackraiyan: Take a look, It's better now? If no, which part you can't understand?

Comment: I believe he meant why this works/what needs to be changed, in which case the answer is to specify `-1` for the `nIconIndex` parameter and null (`Nothing`) for the `phiconLarge` and `phiconSmall` parameters.

Comment: Though I'd like to point out that your `ExtractIconEx` declaration is _**way off**_. Ideally, you shouldn't use **ANY** `Declare Function` solutions that you find because most of them are for VB6, and thus outdated and incorrect. Here is the correct declaration: https://pastebin.com/94US4hGP

Comment: In a previous answer of mine I have an example of using the newer declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612160/3740093

Comment: @VisualVincent: Thank you for your help! I'll use your first example:

`<DllImport("shell32.dll")>
Public Shared Function ExtractIconEx(ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, ByVal phiconLarge As IntPtr(), ByVal phiconSmall As IntPtr(), ByVal nIcons As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function`
But how can I put this into a module? Cause I am getting two errors. `Type 'DllImport' is not defined` and `Methods in a module cannot be declared 'Shared'` For the second one I imagine I should remove the 'Shared' part from my Public Function(?). What should I do for the DllImport?

Comment: Add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` on the top of your code file. Visual Studio should suggest this as an auto-fix. -- And yes, remove `Shared` if you put this in a module.

Comment: @VisualVincent: Can you please give me an example based on my initial code the one I have place in my question, not at the answer? Because I am trying to apply those changes but I get errors like `Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'IntPtr()'.`.

Comment: I already gave you an example: my second link. It's not exactly the same as your question but it shows you how to use the `IntPtr` arrays. Your initial code assumed the function only returned **one** small and **one** large icon, which is incorrect since it returns **all** large and small icons present in the file.